# Running nuclei in Python errors out. It should work but for some reason error's out

Tags: python

This piece pf code will just open a file, iterate through file while running nuclei on each line. For those who are not familiar with nuclei it basically just go out to a domain you specify and checks for CVE's. It can do this because there are dozens of templates in the CVE folder that check for different CVE. Very interested tool. I look forward to progressing so that I can contribute to this project ( ProjectDiscovery if your curious). I just started to write code so I don't understand much but I'm learning. Please help me advance.

```
def cveCheck():
    with open('results.txt', 'rb') as http_list:
        for file_to_scan in http_list:
            with open('cve_results.txt', 'a') as f:
                p1 = subprocess.Popen(['echo', file_to_scan], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                p2 = subprocess.Popen([f'nuclei', '-silent', '-t', '~/tools/nuclei-templates/cves/'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=f)
                output = p2.communicate()
```

This is the error. It spits put 122 of these lines. I'm assuming it does that because there are 122 lines, with a domain on each line sitting in the results.txt file. I've also received another error that states that it can't find the templates which are located in the CVE directory.

```
[FTL] Error, no templates were found.
[FTL] Error, no templates were found.
[FTL] Error, no templates were found.
[FTL] Error, no templates were found.
....
```

Also I wanted to ask if I should be using the threading module for this as well.

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that there is actually a directory named `~/tools/nuclei-templates/cves/` on your system.  You can use that name when typing a `nuclei` command in the shell, because the shell automatically expands that `~` into the actual name of your home directory - but no shell is involved here.  You either need to write the full name of the directory, or use `os.path.expanduser()` to duplicate the shell's behavior.

Comment: @jasonharper I did not know that. I just tried writing out the full path as you suggested and got an error saying `[FTL] Program exiting: no template/templates provided` even they I'm writing the command as I would in the shell, which works in the shell. I'm going to look into `os.path.expanduser` to see what I can learn. It's a good thing that I'm messing up like this in the beginning because I get to read  about a lot of possible solutions and if it doesn't work I can just put it on the back burner so it may come in handy later. Thank you sir.